# Lyrical word order swap

Tags: word-order, style

The Pretenders, from "Who's Who" lyrics:

*It's like a modern work of art*

*Disturbing and lacking in heart*

I'm a bit disturbed too: I'd automatically say "a work of modern art" since the last part is a standing phrase. It also scans identically, so that can't be the reason?! Do you see a subtle difference in meaning? (I think I see, but as a German, I'm rather unqualified...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Modern art" and "a modern *work* of art" would mean two completely different things, especially to anyone that knows about art.

"*Modern art*" is a *noun* - it is the name given to a style of art produced from the 1860s to the 1970s.

"*A modern work of art*" is not a noun, or a noun phrase. It is possible that The Pretenders intended the listener to think of a piece of 'modern art', but if used today the phrase would be understood to mean any kind of *contemporary* art of the era, given that the word 'modern' is being used as an adjective in a phrase, so should be taken at face value.

It's highly possible that the word order of this song was chosen to match the rhythm or the rhyme scheme, and the term "modern art" was not discarded deliberately.

Comment: I think you could make a good case that Dante Gabriel Rossetti and Bridget Riley both produced 'modern art', but they are very different in a lot of ways.

Comment: Aaand a piece of art could be in classic style, even if made in modern times. (Ha, the answer given vaguely agrees with that what I already surmised. I'm not a hopeless case :-)